What are all effects written in the book that can directly influence characters without a resistance check?
So one of my players for the PL 8 game I run has Immunity 200: All Resistible Effects (condensed version of Immunity to effects resisted by Toughness, Fortitude, Will, Parry, and Dodge). Normally this would cost way too much for that PL, but he has the following:
Rapier Hilt of the Red Mage
Immunity 200: All Resistible Effects (Sustained) (Increased Action 2, Concentration 1, Unreliable 5/5, Easily Removable) {24}
Its a sword hilt where the blade is a Projected Elongated Extra Limb that can be extended for attacks. It's destructible and it requires a Move Action to Sustain (I buffed the flaw to work like Increased Action) so there's already counterplay, but I've noticed in some regards not all effects that apply to you aren't necessarily "Resistible" (like Illusions requiring a proactive Insight Checks), and am looking to get a post on Stackexchange that will list all methods as we find them.
Note: This is not a post about the fairness of Immunity 200. I'm the GM and I've deemed it balanced at my table. I am only asking for the written effects that can apply. Examples include Environmental Effects that require Stamina Checks like Suffocation and Starving (not Resistance Checks), Demoralize which calls for a Intimidation vs Insight rather than a Resistance Check, etc.

Truthfully, since you've invented the "all resistible effects" option, there really is no way to say what might be an exception. As the GM, you decide what is or is not "resistable".

As a side note, as per the don't ask page, I'm a bit up in the air as to whether this question would be subjective.

All Resistable Effects is just a result of getting immunities to all effects resistible by Defenses: Dodge, Parry, Will, Toughness, and Fortitude. I'm not sure who originally coined the term I'll have to check back with you on that. Now that I think about it there are Strength Resistance Checks from Grabs so I wonder if that was intended on their part.

For the sake of the question I'm asking for all raw effects you can apply to characters that can automatically succeed any "resistance check", if 200 isn't necessarily the number of points you need for that I'll have to talk to the player who currently has it.

"All resistible effects" is homebrew; we can't answer a designer-intent question from the designer.

I've edited the question to be much more clear on the subject I'm looking for.

Since you have clarified that you are looking for places where the rules don't set a Resistance check, I'm adding a list based off of the Heroes Handbook.
Effects

Illusion: As you note, the text of the rule indicates that you do not get to "resist" an illusion until they have reason to, "Characters encountering an illusion do not receive checks to recognize it as illusory until they interact with it in some fashion" and you noted that you did not include opposed checks or skill rolls among things that are "resistible", so the Insight check doesn't fall under the Immunity.
Non-Attack Concealment: Unless the Concealment is Resistible, there is no resistance check to pierce it.
Attack Concealment: If you are targeting individuals, there is a resistance check, as per the Attack modifier, but for historical reasons, things like smoke grenades use a different version where the Concealment is not resistible, because it applies equally everywhere. I personally think this was a hack that was put in solely to reduce the number of bespoke power effects in 3E, and could have been done more cleanly, but I'm not the game designer.
Luck Control: There is no resistance check for someone negating your Hero Point usage, or forcing you to reroll and take the worse roll.
Mind Reading: This one is a bit ambiguous. It is listed as an opposed check rather than a resistance check in the text, but then the table and one of the Extras (Resistible) describes that as a resistance check.
Environment: You've noted that you don't count Fortitude checks from environmental hazards to be resistible effects, so most of Environment will simply affect the world around you, and then you are affected by that.
Remote Sensing: There is no resistance check for being scried, or even noticing it.
Nullify: This is listed as an Opposed check. There is no mention of it being a resistance check.
Create: By the book, everything that is an attack is Resistible, but simply building structures around someone without actually trapping them the one square is arguably just building things (for example, if someone is in a room with one door, putting a wall in front of the door). This is one of those areas where it requires player-GM cooperation to interpret it, since one could argue that a player should get a chance to do an Indy Roll past the forming barrier, but that might also involve them agreeing to "pay" for their movement in their next turn in advance (since a combat round is assumed to actually involve everything happening at once instead of everyone taking turns moving and attacking)

Power Modfiers
For the sake of completeness, Resistible and Attack (other than the exception of "environment Attack Concealment") add a resistance check to the power effect, whether it had one before or not.
Counters
Much like Nullify, this is an opposed check, not a resistance check.
Skill checks and Environment
Just noting that you have noted that you feel that things like Intimidation, Deception, etc, are not considered "resistible", nor things like Fortitude checks to deal with starvation, cold, and the like, or Will checks to deal with crushing ennui or the distraction of a rave party going on around you.
Let me know if you require any expansion on this, or if you want anything from the Gadget Guides or Power Profiles.

Didn't know Concealment Area Attacks worked like that but it makes sense. Seems a bit odd if you use Perception Area given the point is that you can fail the check.
Morph is probably not resistible for a similar if not the same reason since it doesn't have resistance check in the Attack Extra specific to its own extra list, unlike Insubstantial.

Hmm... I would argue against Morph lacking a check. It is targeting someone, not just generally affecting the environment, although I'm not certain what a good resistance would be, and one could probably argue that, like Illusion, it's not doing anything to the person in question, but rather is imposing some sort of illusion to those around the target. I'd leave that up to the GM.

Tbf I think it's a good take because Morph attacks weren't really causing problems for anyone and it's effectively a illusion that follows a person. Means lower rank Morphs are easier to apply if you have Accuracy (or I suppose just 2 ranks for perception)

Just to get the elephant out of the room, the facile answer is that, as the GM, anything that you decide is not resistible will not be able to be resisted. For example, godlike beings often have PL X "fiat" powers that just work automatically with no save, c.f. Quark from the Freedomverse. And then you get into whether any particular effect is something to be resisted. If your player gets trapped in an elaborate escape room, are the skill challenges "resistible"? If the villain starts taunting them to demoralize them, is that "resistible"? If a psychotic adversary starts killing everyone the hero holds dear, is that "resistible" for the purpose of the Immunity? Those are things that only you can answer.
Other than that, things that affect the world around the character would, by proxy, affect them. Creating a solid shell of stone around them would not technically give them anything to resist (technically, there's a Dodge save to avoid being trapped, but if the shell is larger than their movement speed, there's not much opportunity to argue that they can dodge outside of the confines). Annihilation of the world around them could leave them hanging in a void, or at the bottom of a deep pit (although presumably, they would be safe from the falling damage, since that is resistible). Summoning a massive number of low PL minions around them will not technically affect them, but will force them to fight their way out (possibly burning off all of their uses of their Immunity as they're punched at by PL 1 bystanders).

Resistible "Effects" refers to defined game effects by definition so its arguable a GM's random ruling is not a "effect" (pg. 308), then again effect's definition only refers to powers so that's with a grain of salt. As for Unreliable, the "use" is the activation, not the application of the effect. Until they stop sustaining it, it gets countered, or the weapon breaks, the effect remains regardless of how many times they're hit, as per the interaction with Triggered Powers and Fade's text due to it referring to when you use the power.

For references of the kinds of things I'm looking for here, I've found that opposed checks aren't resistance checks. Demoralizing is a Intimidation Check vs Insight as a kind of direct contest as opposed to normal resistance, similar to how you can still attack and "hit" someone immune to effects resisted by dodge and parry. Suffocation, Starvation, and such are others since they simply require Stamina Checks, Floods just require Athletics Checks to leave, and I have one more I can't put here yet since I have a player looking at this that I can't spoil it to though may edit in later.

Well, then I suppose it's a bit of a tautology. Any effect that you say is not resistible, or not an effect, is not covered by the Immunity.

Self fulfilling though I personally feel such things are in bad faith towards the player who obtained such a ability. If it's at least a game effect that already exists that's something, but what player would feel good about you making a random undefined house rule out of nowhere that conveniently works on them?

@FriendlyNeighborhoodChicken: Immunity is one of those highly subjective things where the cost of any particular immunity is based off of your setting and how the game runs. In a world where all powers are psychic, Immunity to mental powers should cost a lot. In a world where they're rare, it should be cheap. And, as you note, avoiding a player's immunity, particularly hard bought, is rude. If someone is Immune to bullets, you should have people occasionally trying to shoot them (although, of course, smarter opponents will know it's useless and use other tactics).

Ultimately, while we can offer suggestions, or list powers that don't explicitly state a resistance check, ultimately the answer is probably going to come down to what your player and you agree to be fair.

What I've determined for the server to be fair is just playing RAW and they've harkoned it to a flawed enchantment on the sword not seeing (most) environmental hazards, social interactions, and such as things that cannot be resisted out of the nature of the problem being not the effect in question but the character lacking something, like air, food, water, social skills, etc, but regardless of that I'm simply asking for effects that can work on characters that are immune to resistance checks that are listed in the book(s). I feel the examples I've given are good enough references.

Should I reword the question to "What are all the effects you can apply to hostile characters without resistance checks?" or something similar? I'm open to suggestions.

I think that it would be helpful to request a list of powers that state that they do not provide a resistance check, although that might make for a fairly short answer. As much as anything, it would clarify that you are looking for a rule text question, not one about how to run the game or challenge such a character.
